# CKEditor5 within Laravel and Vue application

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, webpack

In my standalone Vue application I build CKEditor5 from source, nothing wrong, build successfully. this Vue application consume API from Laravel backend.

however based on criteria from Sysadmin, we just have 1 subdomain for the entire application. that's make me have to integrate Vue js frontend application within Laravel API backend.

Long story short, I put my Vue js files inside `resources/js` of Laravel instance and then have the following `webpack.mix.js` file:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel applications. By default, we are compiling the CSS
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue();
mix.options({
    postCss: [
        require('autoprefixer')
    ]
})

/**
 * CK Editor Config
 */

const CKEditorWebpackPlugin = require( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin' );
const CKEStyles = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils').styles;
const CKERegex = {
    svg: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/,
    css: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\].+\.css$/,
};

Mix.listen('configReady', webpackConfig => {
    const rules = webpackConfig.module.rules;
    const targetSVG = /(\.(png|jpe?g|gif|webp)$|^((?!font).)*\.svg$)/;
    const targetCSS = /\.css$/;

    // exclude CKE regex from mix's default rules
    // if there's a better way to loop/change this, open to suggestions
    for (let rule of rules) {
        if (rule.test.toString() === targetSVG.toString()) {
            rule.exclude = CKERegex.svg;
        }
        else if (rule.test.toString() === targetCSS.toString()) {
            rule.exclude = CKERegex.css;
        }
    }
});

/**
 * Webpack Config for CK Editor
 */
mix.webpackConfig({
    plugins: [
        new CKEditorWebpackPlugin({
            language: 'en'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.svg$/, //CKERegex.svg,
                use: [ 'raw-loader' ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/, //CKERegex.css,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader',
                        options: {
                            injectType: 'singletonStyleTag',
                            attributes: {
                                'data-cke': true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: CKEStyles.getPostCssConfig({
                            themeImporter: {
                                themePath: require.resolve('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark')
                            },
                            minify: true
                        })
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

after setting up package.json and running `npm install`, I run `npm run dev` and it's fails.

```
    ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/theme/components/toolbar/toolbar.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-8[0].rules[0].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??clonedRuleSet-8[0].rules[0].use[2]!./node_modules/style-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-22[0].rules[0].use[0]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??clonedRuleSet-22[0].rules[0].use[1]!./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/theme/components/toolbar/toolbar.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
SyntaxError

(1:1) Unknown word

> 1 | var api = require("!../../../../../style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js");
    | ^
  2 |             var content = require("!!../../../../../postcss-loader/src/index.js??clonedRuleSet-22[0].rules[0].use[1]!./toolbar.css");
  3 |
```

It's already took me several hours to try and error, but nothing works. any help would be grateful. thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find out what was the issue by any chance? I am struggling with this for the past several hours.

Comment: I believe you did the same mistake as me. I tried to use Laravel Mix v.6 with Webpack v.5 which is not currently supported by CKEditor 5. You need to downgrade Laravel Mix v.5 and Webpack v.4.

Answer (score 0):

there needs to be a "css-loader" in the .css webpack rule.

Comment: You could give an explicit example for clarity